# What is the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

This is an exercise I got from a course of which the deadline has already passed, but I'm still confused. I already found the minimal polynomial of $\alpha := 2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is $x^3 + x^2 -2x -1$.

I have no idea how to find the splitting field of that, however. My professor gave a hint that we need Galois theory for this, but I don't yet see how Galois theory can help here.

All I have so far is that If $K$ is the splitting field, $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ divides $3!$, but it can't be $1$ or $2$, so it's either $3$ or $6$.

Comment: Do you know other roots of that polynomial?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I tried to find it but I couldn't find a useful representation

Comment: Prove that if $a$ is a root then so is $b=(1/a)-a$ (and it is not equal to $a$) as well.

Comment: $X^3+X^2-2X-1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha=2\cos\frac{2\pi}7,$ $2\cos\frac{4\pi}7,$ and $2\cos\frac{6\pi}7$ hence its splitting field is $\Bbb Q[\alpha].$

Comment: @AnneBauval  there is a collection of such things in Reuschle (1875), that follows Gauss . This one is on page 6,   which is called  "6 of 671"  on the lower right.  https://archive.org/details/tafelncomplexer00unkngoog/page/6/mode/2up

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you, it is shirley interesting but it requires efforts to enter into that and I am not motivated (my comment was just a hint for irrationalgirl).

Comment: @AnneBauval  understood. I did place a chapter of D. A. Cox about the method as a pdf at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf  Cox, however, does just a few examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you heard of [cyclotomic fields](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cyclotomic.pdf)? One way to solve this problem is to consider the bigger extension $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_7) \supset \mathbf{Q}$, where $\zeta_7 = e^{2\pi i/7}$. This extension is Galois and abelian, with Galois group isomorphic to $(\mathbf{Z}/7)^\times \cong \mathbf{Z}/6$. Note that $2\cos(2\pi /7) = \zeta_7 +\overline{\zeta}_7 = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6$, so that the field generated by $\alpha$ is a subextension. Since you already found the minimal polynomial, you can use Galois theory and the lattice of subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}/6$ to conclude.

Let me know if you need more context. :)